# I have to make a SDF from URDF

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Dear Gazebo Users,

I need to have a SDF format of the Mobile Robot mp_500 but I'm struggling too much of getting the URDF converted into SDF. Does anyone have any idea how I can convert this file? What is it that i have to change in the URDF file to make it work?

Thank you very much.

E. Raci

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8105/i-have-to-make-a-sdf-from-urdf/) by [edo_raci](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1121/edo_raci/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-03-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2015-03-02**:
Gazebo supports urdf models as well, you don't need to change it into sdf if you don't want to. Do you get any errors when loading the urdf model?

**Comment by [edo_raci](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1121/edo_raci/) on 2015-03-02**:
How can i make these models to spawn in Gazebo, is there a special code or something? So far i only know how to spwan models using gazebos Model Database!

**Comment by [edo_raci](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1121/edo_raci/) on 2015-03-02**:
As soon as i want to load the UR10 in the Gazebo, i have modified it's URDF from .gazebo/models/ur10 and because i wanted to add a sensor to it, however as soon as i want to load it in gazebo i get an error saying:

**Comment by [edo_raci](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1121/edo_raci/) on 2015-03-02**:
Error [Converter.cc:127] Unable to convert from SDF version 1.5 to 1.4
Error [parser.cc:697] XML Element[use_parent_model_frame], child of element[axis] not defined in SDF. Ignoring.[axis]
Error [parser.cc:688] Error reading element 
Error [parser.cc:688] Error reading element 
Error [parser.cc:688] Error reading element 
Error [parser.cc:348] Unable to read element 
Error:   Could not find the 'robot' element in the xml file
at line 81 in /build/buildd/urdfdom-

**Comment by [edo_raci](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1121/edo_raci/) on 2015-03-02**:
urdfdom-0.2.10+dfsg/urdf_parser/src/model.cpp
Error [parser_urdf.cc:2608] Unable to call parseURDF on robot model
Error [parser.cc:273] parse as old deprecated model file failed.
Error [ModelMaker.cc:126] Unable to load file[/home/labor/.gazebo/models/Universal_Robot/ur10.sdf]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo has a command line too that converts URDF to SDF:

`gz sdf -p <URDF>`

You can redirect output to a file.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2015-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [edo_raci](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1121/edo_raci/) on 2015-03-05**:
I get the Error gz:: command not found!  I have placed the URDF file i want to convert into .gazebo/models directory is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Have you looked at the [URDF in Gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_urdf) tutorial?

In particular, make sure that you add an `inertia` element to each `link`.

---

Originally posted by [NickDP](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/964/nickdp/) with karma: 186 on 2015-03-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1